# installing lpsolve for MATLAB on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, matlab, lpsolve

I am trying to install this toolkit for 3 hours.... first, for Python.. I gave up. Then for MATLAB...

http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/MATLAB.htm

It says something about installation(and I read everything at all other websites), but I have no idea of what it says...

Why is it so complicated? It is not like windows, in which for everything I want to install, double-clicking 'setup' or 'install' file on the .zip file installed everything I need.

I am so confused and distressed.. Please help me...

I do not know a bit about Ubuntu, so please explain to me which files I should download(there are a lot of files but I do not know what to download...), and how I could install it with what commands.

Thank you.